# sqlite3 return unknown error in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

hy all i have problem with my program

here is my code

```
# include <iostream>
# include <sqlite3.h>
# include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *res;
int rc;
string nama;
int umur;
rc=sqlite3_open("namaorang.db",&db);
if(rc!=SQLITE_OK)
{
    cout<<sqlite3_errmsg(db);
}
else
{
    cout<<"Nama : ";cin>>nama;
    cout<<"Umur : ";cin>>umur;
    stringstream sql;
    sql<<"INSERT INTO data (nama,umur)VALUES ('"<<nama<<"','"<<umur<<"');";
    rc=sqlite3_prepare(db,sql.str().c_str(),-1,&res,NULL);
    if(rc!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cout<<sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    rc=sqlite3_step(res);
    if(rc!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cout<<sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    }

}
sqlite3_finalize(res);
sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

when i run my program and input the query , this program return unknown error,, how to fix this.. meanwhile the error is unknown,, how to known the error.. thanks for read this

Comment: Do you know what [result code](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) is being returned?

Comment: but my program is success input data into database.. but why the "unknown error" appears??

Comment: I am not sure.  What line of your program makes it appear?  You should step through your code to see when it happens.

Comment: #define SQLITE_NOTFOUND    12   /* Unknown opcode in sqlite3_file_control() */ is it?

Comment: found it!!! the error appear because the condition of rc=sqlite3_step is != SQLITE_OK ,, it should be rc==SQLITE_ROW.. this is my mistake not carefully.. ok thanks for your answer nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if(rc!=SQLITE_OK)
> {
>     cout<<sqlite3_errmsg(db);
>     sqlite3_close(db);
> }
> ```

Seems like you need `return` here, but you continue to work with results after error instead.

Comment: thanks for comment my question ,, and yes you are right about my error.. and i already fix it...